# proper use of 'this' in Java

Tags: java

I'm a beginner Java programmer and just wanted someone to look over some code I'm writing 
please can you confirm if this is the right use of the `this` keyword

```
public class ReadFile {

    private String path; // String to store filename and path. 

    public ReadFile(String path){
        this.path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that code does nothing at all but it is entirely valid.

Comment: Yeah, it seems right, what do you understand of using "this"?

Comment: whenever in doubt, check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @radcliffejh It's not valid: `error: not a statement` `this.path;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using `this`

As some answers above suggest, you can `this` for pointing to a member variable and you could also use it to invoke another constructor from within a constructor.

See below example

```
public class Rectangle {
private int x, y;
private int width, height;

public Rectangle() {
    this(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
    this(0, 0, width, height);
}
public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
...
}
```

Refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) for more information.

Hope this helps

Comment: My pleasure, also make sure you fix that bug in your code from `this.path;` to `this.path=path;`. Peace! :)

Comment: done! :) Also Thanks to everyone else for your comments and advice

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the object instance on which code is being executed. Typical example would be something like you already wrote (btw, `this.path` by itself is not a valid java statement)

```
public class ReadFile {

    private String path; // String to store filename and path. 

    public ReadFile(String path){
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

`this.path` refers to private field `path`, and `path` refers to method parameter.

Comment: Think you should mention that the code that the OP wrote is not valid as `this.path;` is not a valid statement (but your code fixes that problem)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt That's why I wrote "something like you already wrote", but I'll edit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

That use of `this.path` *would* be correct if you were doing something with it, e.g.:

```
this.path = path;
```

Just `this.path;` on its own is invalid in Java.

`this`, in an instance method, refers to the current object instance. In the corrected code above, `this.path` refers to your instance data member, and `path` on its own refers to the `path` argument you specified for `setPath`. For clarity, let's rename the argument:

```
private String path;

public void setPath(String newPath){
    this.path = newPath;
}
```

Another form you'll see frequently (which I *don't advocate*) is this:

```
private String path;

public void setPath(String newPath){
    path = newPath;
}
```

Because there is no other `path` in scope where we've used it, the freestanding `path` symbol there resolves to `this.path` automagically. Some people love that, saves typing `this.`; others feel that it makes the code harder to read because you don't know whether `path` is a local variable, an argument, an instance member, or a class member.

I mention the second form because you said you're a beginner, and you'll see it used in lots of code. Again, I don't advocate it.

Answer (score 0):

In ReadFile function you should do something with this.path which is a private field of your class such as:

```
public ReadFile(String path){
    this.path = path;
}
```